# Que función o método debo utilizar para validar información desde la BD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, un vista con un menú de la cual un link se llama DCER, ese link me trae una vista con un listado de datos que se llama de un controlador y un modelo relacionado a una BD. la cuestión esta es que ese link llamado DCER se muestre siempre y cuando haya información desde la BD sino no se muestre, el paso es lógico con una validación desde el controlador diciendo que si la consulta es null o cero(en este caso se valida con un boolean) pues se muestre la información y el link DCER se muestre.

Pero esa validación se hace siempre y cuando se use el controlador, hay alguna forma o método o función propia de asp que haga el procedimiento anterior desde un principio o inicio de la aplicación, que documentación me puede servir? como debería de hacerlo? muchas gracias.

```
public Boolean EstacionesDecer()
        {
            //Consultamos si hay datos para DCER.
            var RadicadosEstaciones = _context.RadicadoEstacionDb
                .Include(re => re.Estacion.Depto)
                .Include(re => re.Estacion.Mupio)
                .Where(re => re.Estacion.IdUsuario == _contextListas.getUsuarioPadre(User.getUserId()))
                .Where(re => re.IdProceso == 2 && re.Estacion.TipoEstacion == 1);

            //DCER Menu o Sidebar si hay estaciones para DCER
            int dcer = RadicadosEstaciones.Count();
            Boolean estacionDcer;
            if (dcer != 0) 
            { estacionDcer = true; ViewBag.DCER = estacionDcer; } 
            else { estacionDcer = false; ViewBag.DCER = estacionDcer; }

            return  estacionDcer;

        }
```

El anterior es el código desde el controlador, como lo digo solo se ejecuta siempre y cuando sea utilizado, pero se necesita que se renderize o se ejecute desde un inicio de la aplicación. Como este se necesita hacer mas para mostrar mas menú.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicarnos siempre será incluyendo lo relevante de tu código en la pregunta.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Imagino que estas usando JQuery, alguna libreria o framework; yo manejaria la visualizacion desde el front, mas que del backend

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Paulo Urbano. Uno de tus métodos de script debería dispararse en el evento document.ready() y debe pedir los DCER en el controlador. Con la respuesta construyes el menú. Lo otro que podrías intentar es que el viewmodel lleve esa propiedad a la vista, y la vista renderice el menú dependiendo de ese boolean.